# Unable to add "External Jars" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

[The Image of the Eclipse] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QXMf.png)

I installed Selenium using Homebrew. But I am unable to add the jar files to Eclipse. They are not clickable. I tried extracting the selenium file on the terminal but it says I am unable to extract.

Comment: You have to choose either _Modulepath_ or _Classpath_ first. When in doubt, add it to the _Classpath_ and make sure you have not a `module-info.java` file in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much
It works now
I think the issue was with the module-info.java file